# How to create a calculated field that equals one of many attributes

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

Having tha following data

```
Product   AttributeType  AttributeValue
Ferrari   Color          Red
Ferrari   Wheels         4
Porsche   Color          Silver
Porsche   Wheels         4
Yamaha    Color          Black
Yamaha    Wheels         2
```

How can i create a calculated field "Color"/"Wheels" that gives me the respective color/wheels?

I tried to do something like

```
{FIXED [AttributeValue]: [AttributeType]="Color"}
```

But Tableau complained that `[AttributeType]="Color"` is not an aggregation function.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you want a table like that:
`Product |AttributeType |AttributeValue |Color |Wheels`
`Ferrari |Color |Red |Red |4`
`Ferrari |Wheels |4 |Red |4`
Sorry for formatting but I hope it's still understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simpler to reshape your data to have Color column and a Wheels column, but if you don't want to do that, the following aggregate calculation works.

```
attr(if AttributeType = "Color" then AttributeValue end) +  "/" +
attr(if AttributeType = "Wheels" then AttributeValue end)
```

If you have multiple colors or wheels attributes given the dimensions in play, the attr() function will return "*"

Comment: I cannot reshape the data but your expression works. Thank you